# Redirecting to Subdomain with Blueshost Server

Tags: php, html, apache, ftp, indexing

So here is my subdomain http://amabini.com/faithmabini/
now i want to index or redirect the user to the url below when they visit the subdomain, how can i do that? How will I index this url:
 http://amabini.com/faithmabini/mabini/Webpages/Home.php

Answer (score 0):

For a quick redirect, you can do:

```
header("Location: http://amabini.com/faithmabini/mabini/Webpages/Home.php");
exit;
```